# Simple facebook Login

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

Here's my code. This code executes in the `onClick(View view)` of an `ImageView`. When I click it, it sends me to the facebook native app. Then I log in, BUT the session returns closed. What am I doing wrong?

```
Session.openActiveSession(getActivity(), true, new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if(session.isOpened()) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Logged in Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, The reason which `session.isOpened()` is always returning false was because the KeyHash that I got using the `keytool` command, was wrong. I had to re-get the KeyHash.